# How to return a series calculation using numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to solve a problem in which for an scalar variable `x` ( ∈(0,2) ) and positive integer `N`, I have to calculate and return the notation in the image below. I am a one-day np fetus and I am having a problem. Would you please look at my code?

Hint:  use `np.arange`, `np.sum`, `np.multiply.accumulate`

[image: equation]

```
import numpy as np
def mysin(x,N):
    k=1
    arr=np.arange(k,N+1)
    for i in arr:
        i=(-1**(k-1))*(x**(2*k-1))/np.math.factorial(2*k-1)
    arr=np.sum(i)
    return arr

raise NotImplementedError()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to loop over the power array explicitly, if you raise a number to a power which is an array then Numpy will perform that operation element wise. The factorial can also be compute inside Numpy, using the `np.multiply.accumulate` function and then selecting every second element since the factorial is `(2k - 1)!`:

```
k = np.arange(1, N+1)
factorial = np.multiply.accumulate(np.arange(1, 2*N).astype(float))[::2]
return np.sum((-1)**(k-1) * x**(2*k-1) / factorial)
```

Comment: Nice! Clever usage of np.multiply.accumulate.

Comment: Thank you but could you explain more about the [::2] because the factorial is 2K-1?

Comment: @jsl5703 In the last iteration we need to compute `(2N - 1)!` so for that we need all the numbers from `1` up to `2*N` and hence `np.arange(1, 2*N)`. Now becase we need to compute `(2k-1)!` at every iteration that means we just need to skip every second element, starting at 1: `k = 1 --> 1!, k = 2 --> 3!, k = 3 --> 5!, etc`. Because `np.multiply.accumulate(np.arange(1, 2*N))` computed the factorial of every number from 1 through 2N we need to skip every second element as per the multiplication `2k`.